# Ubuntu 16 Desktop pxeboot Network Manager not working

Tags: networking, system-installation, network-manager, ubiquity

I have been working on a pxeboot setup with a preseed automated install for Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I have everything working except networking. Whenever I do a pxeboot install (automated or manual) Network Manager does not grab the network connection. After reboot, when the desktop comes up, Network Manager lists no connections and no managed devices. However the /etc/network/interfaces file does have the main ethernet interface in it's list and it's set for manual. I realize it's probably wise not to have network manager take over the interface *during* installation however after reboot it would be nice if control was handed over to Network Manager. I'm able to edit /etc/network/interfaces and if I remove the primary ethernet entries, save, and then restart Network Manager it finds the interface and starts managing it.

The Ubiquity Automation guide indicates that the d-i netcfg commands are not supported during a Ubiquity install which doesn't help - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation

Here is my preseed file:

```
#### Contents of the preconfiguration file (for xenial)
### Localization
# Preseeding only locale sets language, country and locale.
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US

# Keyboard selection.
# Disable automatic (interactive) keymap detection.
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

### User Creation
# To create a normal user account.
d-i passwd/user-fullname string user
d-i passwd/username string user
d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password <removed>
d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

# Set to true if you want to encrypt the first user's home directory.
d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false

### Clock and time zone setup
# Controls whether or not the hardware clock is set to UTC.
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean false

# You may set this to any valid setting for $TZ; see the contents of
# /usr/share/zoneinfo/ for valid values.
d-i time/zone string US/Eastern

# Controls whether to use NTP to set the clock during the install
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean false

### Disk setup
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

### Controlling how partitions are mounted
# The default is to mount by UUID, but you can also choose "traditional" to
# use traditional device names, or "label" to try filesystem labels before
# falling back to UUIDs.
d-i partman/mount_style select uuid

### Boot loader installation
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
```

Here is my Append line in the pxelinux file. This is all one line but I've made it a little more readable here.

```
append automatic-ubiquity
auto=true 
initrd=ubuntu16desktop/initrd.lz 
url=http://192.168.1.30/ubuntu16desktop/preseed.seed 
keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us
boot=casper 
netboot=nfs
nfsroot=192.168.1.30:/var/ftp/pub/ubuntu16desktop
interface=auto
```

After install this is what's in my /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet manual
```

All I have to do is remove the last two lines and restart network manager but this kind of takes the "hands off" out of hands off install. Is there a preferable way to have Ubiquity installer setup the Network Manager during a pxeboot install or what's the best hack and slash way to do this?

Comment: I wonder why it says `iface ens3 inet manual`. Did you change it or did it come that way? I suspect it will work perfectly with: `iface ens3 inet dhcp`

Comment: the name of the interface appears to be somewhat random now as of the systemd change. My CentOS boxes have this as well. I believe I can rename the interface but it doesn't matter much. However I WANT network manager to be in charge and not use /etc/network/interfaces for managing the network. EDIT: here is more info on the interface naming - https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/